# Unable to redirect website on HTTPS in Django after using SSL_REDIRECT = True

Tags: django, linux, ssl, django-rest-framework, server

I have created a website with an admin page and REST APIs, I am using the centOS server to deploy the website. I have this code in my settings.py file:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # 'djangosecure.middleware.SecuritsyMiddleware'
]
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [ 'http://127.0.0.1:4200',
                          'http://localhost:4200',
                         'http://*']

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "https")
```

If I remove the SSL_Redirect lines from code then the server runs properly but it runs on HTTP.
I want my website to run on HTTPS, That is why I am using these settings.
Due to these settings, my website doesn't run at all and the browser gives a response as the site took too long to respond.

When I see logs, all the endpoints are giving 301 as a response code. I am not able to get that why this happening. I have gone through all the Django SSL Documentation but I did not find any solution.

LOGS:

```
2021-09-25 16:24:18,091 autoreload 598 INFO Watching for file changes with StatReloader
2021-09-25 16:24:19,585 server 110 INFO HTTP/2 support enabled
2021-09-25 16:24:19,585 server 121 INFO Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8001:interface=0.0.0.0
2021-09-25 16:24:19,588 server 155 INFO Listening on TCP address 0.0.0.0:8001
2021-09-25 16:24:24,520 http_protocol 160 DEBUG HTTP b'GET' request for ['157.38.102.103', 63772]
2021-09-25 16:24:24,523 http_protocol 256 DEBUG HTTP 301 response started for ['157.38.102.103', 63772]
2021-09-25 16:24:24,523 http_protocol 223 DEBUG HTTP close for ['157.38.102.103', 63772]
2021-09-25 16:24:24,523 http_protocol 269 DEBUG HTTP response complete for ['157.38.102.103', 63772]
2021-09-25 16:24:24,523 runserver 153 INFO [32mHTTP GET /admin/ 301 [0.00, 157.38.102.103:63772][0m
```

It will be very helpful if someone can provide a solution to this problem.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Are you running your site behind a webserver like nginx or Apache?

Comment: Yes, its a server of Apache with PHPMyAdmin and MySQL